# Bookshelf.js fetch rows with related (joined) tables - limiting number of related rows

Tags: javascript, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am trying to achieve pagination in Bookshelf.js, and limit not just the number of models (**Author** in my code), but also the number of items in every model (**books** in my code).

Here is the code:

```js
Author.where('postedBy', userId).fetchPage({
    pageSize: 10,
    page: 1,
    withRelated: [
        { 'books': function(qb) { qb.limit(10) } }
    ]
})
```

So, what I expect is:

```js
{ author_1: [ book_1, ..., book_10 ], ..., author_10: [ book_1, ..., book_10 ] }
```

But instead I get:

```js
{ author_1: [ book_1, ..., book_7 ], author_2: [ book_1, ..., book_3 ], author_N: [/*8 other collections are empty*/] }
```

So it just limits the total number of Authors to 10, AND overall number of items in the query to 10.
Instead I want to have 10 Authors and up to 10 books in every author's collection.

Is there a way to achieve that with Bookshelf.js & Knex.js?

Comment: So, there's currently a limitation with Bookshelf that explains that weird behavior. It's actually related with [issue #141](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues/141) even tough it may look different. The thing is that the `qb.limit(10)` is being applied to the `SELECT` query that fetches all the related books. Bookshelf actually runs two queries in this case, the first to get the authors, and a second one to get the books by limiting the `author_id`, so that's why you're only getting 10 books overall.

Comment: @devius thanks, that makes sense! For future researches - I found more info in #141 thread: "every time you use the query builder interface (qb.something() in your example) you're using Knex, and Knex has no knowledge of Bookshelf models". I've just put .limit(100) on the whole query - 10 authors * 10 books, and serve data to the API using .slice(0, 10) just in case. One ugly solution but it's OK at least for now.